# Python Scrapy tutorial KeyError: 'Spider not found:

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to write my first scrapy spider, Ive been following the tutorial at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html But I'm getting an error "KeyError: 'Spider not found: "

I think I'm running the command from the correct directory (the one with the scrapy.cfg file)

```
(proscraper)#( 10/14/14@ 2:06pm )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/hacks/prosum-scraper/scrapy
   tree
.
├── scrapy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── juno_spider.py
└── scrapy.cfg

2 directories, 7 files
(proscraper)#( 10/14/14@ 2:13pm )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/hacks/prosum-scraper/scrapy
   ls
scrapy  scrapy.cfg
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
(proscraper)#( 10/14/14@ 2:13pm )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/hacks/prosum-scraper/scrapy
   scrapy crawl juno
/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py:184: UserWarning: You do not have the service_identity module installed. Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity>. Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL tosupport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostnameverification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
  verifyHostname, VerificationError = _selectVerifyImplementation()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
    spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 44, in create
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: juno'
```

This is my virtualenv:

```
(proscraper)#( 10/14/14@ 2:13pm )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/hacks/prosum-scraper/scrapy
   pip freeze
Scrapy==0.24.4
Twisted==14.0.2
cffi==0.8.6
cryptography==0.6
cssselect==0.9.1
ipdb==0.8
ipython==2.3.0
lxml==3.4.0
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pycparser==2.10
queuelib==1.2.2
six==1.8.0
w3lib==1.10.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Here is the code for my spider wth the name attribute filled in:

```
(proscraper)#( 10/14/14@ 2:14pm )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/hacks/prosum-scraper/scrapy
   cat scrapy/spiders/juno_spider.py 
import scrapy

class JunoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "juno"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.juno.co.uk/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.juno.co.uk/dj-equipment/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: /home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py:184: UserWarning: You do not have the service_identity module installed. Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity>. Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL tosupport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostnameverification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
you need to install that module

Comment: I dont think that should affect the finding of the command

Comment: OK i installed it ```pip install service_identity``` I still get the same error

Comment: try to run your command on the directory where the `items.py` is

Comment: Hmm tried that, still no luck :(

Comment: interesting, it has always worked for me. did you create your scrapy following the tutorial?

Comment: try recreate your project like this:
`scrapy startproject junoproject`
`scrapy genspider juno juno.co.uk`
edit your spider as you posted, and run again.
I can run this absolutely fine

Comment: I wouldn't call the folder with `items.py`, `settings.py` etc. "scrapy". choose another name

Comment: Yes good point, I renamed the project and it worked. Great debiggin!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you start a project with *scrapy* as the project name it creates the directory structure you printed:

```
.
├── scrapy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── juno_spider.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

But using *scrapy* as the project name has a collateral effect. If you open the generated `scrapy.cfg` you will see that your default settings points to your `scrapy.settings` module.

```
[settings]
default = scrapy.settings
```

When we cat the `scrapy.settings` file we see:

```
BOT_NAME = 'scrapy'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scrapy.spiders'
```

Well, nothing strange here. The bot name, the list of modules where Scrapy will look for spiders, and the module where to create new spiders using the genspider command. So far, so good.

Now let's check the *scrapy* library. It has been properly installed under your proscraper isolated virtualenv under the  `/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy` directory. Remember that `site-packages` is always added to the `sys.path`, that contains all the paths from where Python is going to search for the modules. So, guess what... the scrapy library also has a `settings` module `/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings` that imports `/home/tim/.virtualenvs/proscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py` that holds the default values for all the settings. Special attention to the default `SPIDER_MODULES` entry:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = []
```

Maybe you are starting to get what is happening. Choosing *scrapy* as the project name also generated a `scrapy.settings` module that clashes with the scrapy library `scrapy.settings`. And here is where the order in how the corresponding paths were inserted in `sys.path` will make Python to import one or the other. First to appear wins. In this case the scrapy library settings wins. And hence the `KeyError: 'Spider not found: juno'`.

To solve this conflict you could rename your project folder to another name, let's say `scrap`:

```
.
├── scrap
│   ├── __init__.py
```

Modify your `scrapy.cfg` to point to the proper `settings` module:

```
[settings]
default = scrap.settings
```

And update your `scrap.settings` to point to the proper spiders:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrap.spiders']
```

But as @paultrmbrth suggested I would recreate the project with another name.